# CSS issue with relative sizes

Tags: css, font-size

I have this code

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   .frame                  {width: 50em; border: 1px solid black}
   .frame  label           {width: 20em; display: block; text-align:right; border: 1px solid green} 
   .frame label span       {width: 20em; display: block; font-size: .5em; border: 1px solid red; text-align: right}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="frame">
   <label>
    Label
    <span>
     Span
    </span>
   </label>
  </div>
 </body>
```

The red `<span>` is set to `20em`. But it should be as large as the green `<label>`. I want to keep the font-size small in the red part though. Unfortunately even if the `font-size` is half as large, I can't use `40em` to get the same size.
Any idea howto solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don’t declare a width for the `SPAN` element (or `width:100%`), its property `display:block` would already make sure that its width would be the full available width.

Answer (score 2):

px is not an option as I do want to keep the design "scalable". I just found out, that it works with "width: 100%" for the span.

Comment: Yes, width: 100%; would set it to 100% of the containing element--which might be a better design for you.

Comment: you should put this in your question earlier. I thought that all you want is to solve that problem. (as stated in your question) :-s

Answer (score 1):

Note that using em's is [relative to the containing em size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)). When using px's or pt's your size is relative to screen resolution. Which is why you were getting a 20em's worth of width for the red `span` when inside of a 20em label.